# How to make a sphere which number of faces is divisible by 5?

Tags: mesh, faces

Hy all,
I am a beginner in Blender, I get all things I want done eventually, but this one is a total mystery to me, either it is too simple or simply to hard :):
Original or default UV sphere mesh has 32 faces which make circumference of the sphere (x,y direction), but I want to make a sphere which number of faces are divisible by 5, I+ve tried everything, subdividing, decimating...but can not get number divisible by 5. Merging or dissolving edges is not an option since I want even faces.
Does anyone have any suggestion? Or script perhaps?
Thank you,
Tasha

Comment: when you create a sphere hit F6 button to show properties where you can adjust the division of the sphere.

Comment: if segments*rings = a number finishing with 0 or 5, it is divisible by 5

Comment: The answer here is outdated. If you want Blender 2.8 look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130930/how-to-change-number-of-vertices-in-add-object-in-2-8

Answer (score 2):

Hit <kbd>T</kbd> to bring out the Tool Shelf. In the lower part of it, there should be a section where you can set the properties of newly added objects. If there isn't, put the mouse pointer on the little **+** sign and pull up.
[image]
[image]

Comment: For Blender 2.8 see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130930/how-to-change-number-of-vertices-in-add-object-in-2-8