# How to change number of vertices in add object in 2.8?

Tags: vertices

I'm very new to Blender and following tutorials with the old Blender UI is tricky in 2.8 to say the least. I am trying to find how to perform this function in 2.8
Prior to 2.8, Shift + A > Mesh > Cylinder created a new cylinder and had this menu available in the toolbox to edit the number of vertices in the object

[image]

I cant find this menu in 2.8 and I am unable to change the vertices of the starting object. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: When you do an action, do you see that little box in the bottom left that briefly shows which action was done? In Nicolas example he has clicked on that little button to expand it. I was confused at first about this too and just so happened to figure it out yesterday.

Answer (score 29):

The "*Adjust last operation*" menu is found at the bottom left of the viewport. You may need to click to expand it, as it appears collapsed by default.

[image]

Alternatively, you can look under *Edit > Adjust last operation*, or hit <kbd>F9</kbd>.

Comment: Is there any way to set it as a default value (i.e.: 12 vertices is ALWAYS more useful to me than 32 and I'd rather not like to change it EVERY time I add a cylinder, a cone, a circle, ...)?

Comment: Is there also a way to do this *after* we've created the mesh, and after we've done many actions after that? It seems like this relies on assuming the sphere was created in the very last operation.

Comment: No, there is no way to change it after you've done other actions, since your actions would likely change the vertices positions, making it impossible to change the starting point, i.e. the number and position of vertices and loops that were at the foundation of your actions. If you have edited a mesh and you need to adjust its topology, try the Subdivision Surface or (in the opposite direction) the Decimate modifier.